# Is it possible to run Edge.js on a 32-bit environment?

Tags: node.js, x86, 32-bit, edge.js

I am looking at the Edge.js docmentation [here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/tree/master#building-on-ubuntu) and the instructions are for 64-bit Ubuntu. Is it possible to have Edge.js running on 32-bit Ubuntu instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

From the very docs you linked:

> High level, you **must** have Node.js x64 and Mono x64 installed on the machine before you can install Edge.js. (emphasis mine)